# Meteor.subscribe callback function, saved to Session but returns undefined

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, reactive-programming

I have this profile.js file in /client/

```
/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
✚  subscribe
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/

    var currentUser, currentUserInterests

    Meteor.subscribe("tikiUser", function(){

        Session.set("currentTikiUser", tikiUser.find({}).fetch())

    })


/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
✚  helpers
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/

    Template.profileTags.helpers({

        isActive:function(){

            currentUser = Session.get("currentTikiUser")
            currentUserInterests = currentUser.userInterests

            console.log(currentUserInterests)


        }

    })
```

I'm trying to get the value (in my helper) that is inside currentUser.userInterests but it always returns "undefined". However, if i console.log(currentUser) in the helper, i get the correct object but only for the first time. The second time (when i refresh the page) i get this exepction:

- Exception in template helper: .isActive

Why is that?

thx,

Comment: Cursor is a reactive source, you don't need  to store in another reactive source(sessions), you can write `tikiUser.find({}).fetch()` wherever you want it is a reactive source

Comment: and also are you the publications is not changing?

Comment: Hi, your suggestion is not working, now i'm always having undefined.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with minimum code at meteorpad.com